# How to run sense plugin for elasticsearch without kibana?

Tags: spring, elasticsearch, spring-data-elasticsearch, nosql

Actually we have production elasticsearch server for which we dont have sense plugin installed for kibana.

So usually I statup local elastcsearch server and local kibana. Then with local sense plugin I will query production server. I know this is not the correct way.

Is there any easy way to query production server without disturbing it using sense plugin of Marvel ?

Comment: You may use the Chrome Sense extension which runs on a bare Chrome browser: https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/sense-beta/lhjgkmllcaadmopgmanpapmpjgmfcfig?hl=en

Comment: I use it... But it is outdated and not as good as plugin

Answer (score 1):

Sense plug in is available only as a Chrome extension, or with kibana. You can only find the Beta version of sense on Chrome now. If you want alternative ways to query, you can try these:

- elasticsearch-head: [elasticsearch-head](http://mobz.github.io/elasticsearch-head/) is one of the oldest plugins out there. You can access the main cluster at `http://localhost:9200/_plugin/head/` which has the cluster overview.
- elasticsearch-kopf: [elasticsearch-kopf](https://github.com/lmenezes/elasticsearch-kopf) is similar to elasticsearch-head and also allows you to send arbitrary requests to elasticsearch. It also contains a request history, highlighting and formatting of requested document, but it does not have the auto completion feature.
- Inquisitor: [Inquisitor](https://github.com/polyfractal/elasticsearch-inquisitor) is a tool to help you understand Elasticsearch queries. Besides other options it allows you to execute search queries.
- Elastic-Hammer: [Elastic-Hammer](https://github.com/andrewvc/elastic-hammer) can either be set up locally or alternatively, you can use the online version. Index and type can be chosen from the ones available in the cluster. There is no formatting in the query field, you can't even use tabs for indentation, but errors in your query are displayed in the panel on top of the results while typing. The response is displayed in a table, matching fields are automatically highlighted. Because of the limited possibilities when entering text the plugin seems to be more useful when it comes to the analyzing part or for pasting existing queries. It is a quite useful query tool that will display syntactic errors in your query and format images and links in a pretty response. It even offers autocompletion though not as elaborated as the one Sense and Marvel are providing: It will display any allowed term, no matter the context. So you can't really see which terms currently are allowed but only that the term is allowed at all. Nevertheless this can be useful. Searches can also be saved in local storage and executed again.

You can read up more here, the answer [source](http://blog.florian-hopf.de/2014/06/goodbye-sense-welcome-alternatives.html)

---